# How to draw line between two nodes placed in different Panes / Regions

Tags: javafx, draw, shapes

I am tryin to draw a genealogy tree. In my tree, I store information about ex partners. So the Panel (Region) for person shoud looking like this

```
Z * * * Z * * * Z * * * X --- Y
```

Where Z represent exPartner,  X represent Persion and Y represent current Wife / Husband

And now I would like to draw line to connect current relation  with  children. And ec relations with children.  (graphicaly there will be a line beetwen Z and *)

But when the person is in the other region LayoutX and LayoutX property return  relative value.
 How Can I do that, and how dynamicaly resize this Panel ? I would like that Z should be allways at middle of line Horizontal line connecting children.

Comment: Can you give a little more detail on the relevant part of the scene graph structure? Presumably the nodes you are connecting have some common ancestor in the scene graph? What are you intending to use as the parent of the `Line`?

Comment: The common ancessos is AnchorPane.  And next the Panels will extend Region or AnchorPane... I dont have any idea how it should be drawing.  Maybe as Panel ext AnchorPane containing list of Panels.. etc.. ?

Comment: So you would just add the lines directly to the anchor pane that is the common ancestor, presumably?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given any node, you can get its bounds in the coordinate system of any other node in the same scene graph with:

```
Node nodeOfInterest = ... ;
Node anotherNode = ... ;

// ...

Bounds boundsInScene = nodeOfInterest.localToScene(nodeOfInterest.getBoundsInLocal());
Bounds boundRelativeToAnotherNode = anotherNode.sceneToLocal(boundsInScene);
```

So assuming you have some kind of pane which is a common ancestor to two nodes you want to connect, you can do this:

```
Pane commonAncestor = ... ;
Node n1 = ... ;
Node n2 = ... ;

Bounds n1InCommonAncestor = getRelativeBounds(n1, commonAncestor);
Bounds n2InCommonAncestor = getRelativeBounds(n2, commonAncestor);
Point2D n1Center = getCenter(n1InCommonAncestor);
Point2D n2Center = getCenter(n2InCommonAncestor);

Line connector = new Line(n1Center.getX(), n1Center.getY(), n2Center.getX(), n2Center.getY());
commonAncestor.getChildren().add(connector);

// ...

private Bounds getRelativeBounds(Node node, Node relativeTo) {
    Bounds nodeBoundsInScene = node.localToScene(node.getBoundsInLocal());
    return relativeTo.sceneToLocal(nodeBoundsInScene);
}

private Point2D getCenter(Bounds b) {
    return new Point2D(b.getMinX() + b.getWidth() / 2, b.getMinY() + b.getHeight() / 2);
}
```

Comment: didn;t work for me :(  The line is draw from 0.0.   In my case, I think that I want to draw my tree in recurency. So For Head I wil create object Panel extending AnchorPane for example. In this Pane I will have a HBox with Panels to represent children.. etc... What do you thinking about this solution ?  or could we take a point ensemble ?

Comment: @VANILKA I assume you are computing these after layout, right? It all works for me, so if it's not working you need to edit your question with a [MCVE].

Comment: @VANILKA I meant after layout had been performed (e.g. in response to a user event). Simply setting something's `layoutX` and `layoutY` properties will not cause layout to be performed. (A node's bounds are only computed as part of the layout pass.)

Comment: Ok when I set  LayoutX and Y for . First element I remarked la difference. Extept the line is not drawing from center but from left corner to left corner of element : http://imgur.com/hacq84A

Comment: Ok it works..  The size of  Rectangle was 0..  Thx for your help