# Draw Arrows over Nodes

Tags: javafx

I want to draw arrows in a group over my grid view. The example works fine with 3x3 grid. But if I change this size to e.g. 4x4 these arrows are on the wrong place.
I colorized the source field (green) and the destination field (red) to make sure I target the right cells. The program clears the arrowGroup and draws two arrows every 3s.

[image: GUI working example]

```
import eu.lestard.grid.GridModel;
import eu.lestard.grid.GridView;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.geometry.Bounds;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Point2D;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Line;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import static javafx.scene.paint.Color.RED;

public class App extends Application {

    private GridView<States> gridView;
    private StackPane stackPane;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
        stackPane = new StackPane();
        borderPane.setCenter(stackPane);

        Group arrowGroup = new Group();
        GridModel<States> gridModel = new GridModel<>();

        gridModel.setDefaultState(States.EMPTY);
        gridModel.setNumberOfColumns(3);
        gridModel.setNumberOfRows(3);

        gridView = new GridView<>();
        gridView.setGridModel(gridModel);
        
        stackPane.getChildren().add(gridView);
        stackPane.getChildren().add(arrowGroup);

        final Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane, 500, 500);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        new Thread(() -> {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 1000000; i++) {
                Platform.runLater( () -> {
                    arrowGroup.getChildren().clear();
                    drawArrow(arrowGroup, new Point2D(0,0), new Point2D(2,1));
                    drawArrow(arrowGroup, new Point2D(1,1), new Point2D(0,2));
                });
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Thread.interrupted();
                }
            }
            }).start();
    }

    // getRelativeBounds, getCenter based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/43119383/772883
    private void drawArrow(Group group, Point2D from, Point2D to) {
        final Line line = new Line();

        System.out.println(String.format("Draw arrow from cell %s to %s", from, to));
        System.out.println(String.format("group coord %s %s", group.getLayoutX(), group.getLayoutY()));

        // Note: (X,Y) -> (Column, Row) => access via (Y,X)
        final Pane cellPane = gridView.getCellPane(gridView.getGridModel().getCell(((int) from.getY()), (int) from.getX() ));
        final Pane cellPane2 = gridView.getCellPane(gridView.getGridModel().getCell((int) to.getY() , (int) to.getX()));

        cellPane.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.DARKGREEN, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));
        cellPane2.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(RED, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));

        Bounds n1InCommonAncestor = getRelativeBounds(cellPane, gridView);
        Bounds n2InCommonAncestor = getRelativeBounds(cellPane2, gridView);

        Point2D n1Center = getCenter(n1InCommonAncestor);
        Point2D n2Center = getCenter(n2InCommonAncestor);

        System.out.println(String.format("Draw arrow from coord %s to %s", n1Center, n2Center));

        System.out.println(n1Center);
        System.out.println(n2Center);

        line.setStartX(n1Center.getX());
        line.setStartY(n1Center.getY());
        line.setEndX(n2Center.getX());
        line.setEndY(n2Center.getY());
        group.getChildren().add(line);
    }

    private Bounds getRelativeBounds(Node node, Node relativeTo) {
        Bounds nodeBoundsInScene = node.localToScene(node.getBoundsInLocal());
        return relativeTo.sceneToLocal(nodeBoundsInScene);
    }

    private Point2D getCenter(Bounds b) {
        return new Point2D(b.getMinX() + b.getWidth() / 2, b.getMinY() + b.getHeight() / 2);
    }

    public static enum States {
        EMPTY,
        X,
        O
    }
}
```

(If have replaced the arrows with lines to reduce the code.)

There is a gist withe the code and a gradle buildfile:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c54b12ee04b7e45f2e9f58e9de1d1df0

It would be great if somebody could explain why does only work with 3x3. Is there any better option than a group?

Comment: A `Group` takes on the common bounds of all its child nodes. A `StackPane`, by default, centers all its child nodes. I suspect your example only works because it happens that centering the smallest rectangle containing both arrows gives the desired effect. (Try changing the destination cell for the second arrow to (0,1), for example, still with a 3x3 grid, and see if it still works.) BTW don't post links to code; you should create a standalone [MCVE] that can be run just from the code you post in the question, if you want to make it easy for people to help you.

Comment: You are right this also breaks the 3x3 grid. Is group the wrong container then? I understand the problem a little bit but don't know a solution. Since I use this library for the gridview it was not easy to strip this out. I tried in the first place to replace with a GridPane but had other issues when resizing. Instead I tried to compact the issue to one Java-File and provide a gradle file. If someone would like to help he would only need this two files.

Comment: I would probably replace the `Group` with a `Pane`. The real problem though is the `StackPane` centering the two different pieces; so either replace that with a `Pane` or set its alignment to top left. Again, just guessing really because I can't test without a complete example.

Comment: Replacing the `Group` with a `Pane` fixed it right away. Setting the `StackPane` to `Pos.TOP_LEFT` results in another offset. That's the result of testing both approaches without further investigation. If you write an seperate answer for this I would mark it as resolved.